# Writing in notepad using process

Tags: java, file-io, process, notepad

I'm trying to make a process that opens some text file and writes a message. But my process can't write; it just opens the file:

```
Process pr = new ProcessBuilder("notepad","C:\\Users\\I\\Desktop\\1.txt").start();
OutputStream outputStream = pr.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
printWriter.println("Process1");
printWriter.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure notepad supports this kind of operation?

Comment: In the title you say you want to write to notepad, then in the question you say you want to write to a file. Which of the two do you want to do?

Comment: I want to open notepad with process and write in the particular file, so that it is visible in an opened notepad window.

Comment: You want to open a blank notepad, and then write text to it and have the text just appear?

Comment: I'm asking if this is possible, but what is really confusing me is that why when i'm writing in this file, it doesn't save?

Comment: I am not sure if notepad will refresh the file once OutputStream/PrintWriter has written to it, my guess is no it wont, that's why you don't see "Process1" in the text file

Comment: j.con, yes, that's what i want

Comment: When I run process again file doesn't contain changes

Comment: Could it be that it fails to write to the file because notepad has opened and locked the file? In this case I think you need to 1) close notepad 2) write to file 3) open file in notepad

Comment: I trying make it, because want to working with processes. I want work with one resource with many processes in one program simultaneously. For that, I trying to write process to writing in file using  notepad. So file it's just recourse, writing to a file is not my main problem, is just a method of using a resource, as well as reading from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if notepad has command line APIs.

According to [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389) there may be no such API, or an option to refresh the notepad editor.

Comment: Can you give me, please, an example of a text editor with such API?

Comment: I know some web browsers can do that in command line, for example midori browser, you can use `midori -a http://www.google.com/ -i 120 -e Fullscreen`. Source: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/auto-refresh-for-midori